# Get file directory name in webpack config

Tags: webpack

There is many shortcuts in webpack config: `[name]`, `[path]`... any loader can provide his own (e.g *css-loader* provides `[local]` shortcut).

How can I get file directory (the last in the chain) for the `[path]`?

Here is my config:

```
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  loaders: [
    'style',
    'css?localIdentName=[path]', // Path - full chain, but I need only the last dir
  ],
}
```

`[path`] here is, for example, *src-components-button*, but I need only the last - *button*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following code:

'css?localIdentName=[folder]'
https://github.com/webpack/loader-utils#interpolatename

As sample for cssModules name:

'style!css?localIdentName=[folder]**[local]**[hash:base64:5]'

This issue is discussed in the topic:https://github.com/webpack/css-loader/issues/101

Comment: In your answer you used `:base64:5` that means five character hashed names. why I can not set `:base64:3`, when I use three instead of five some classNames generate with same name.